# Volume of tetrahedron with regard to opposite sides

Tags: geometry, vectors, volume, solid-geometry

Prove that the volume of the tetrahedron $ABCD$ is $\frac{1}{6}AB\cdot CD\cdot EF \sin x$ where $EF$ is the shortest distance between $AB$ and $CD,$ and $x$ is the angle between these two lines.
I have attempted the proof using vector methods, but have not got very far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you express $EF$ with vector methods? If not, where exactly are you stuck? This information helps people write up better answers.

Comment: I know that the direction vector of EF is the cross product of the direction vectors of AB and CD, but can't see how to use this fact in relation to the angle between the lines.

Comment: Do you know that the volume of the tetrahedron is $\dfrac16 \det(\vec{AB},\vec{AC},\vec{AD})$ (in absolute value)? It is a good starting point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AD'BC'A'DB'C$ be a parallelepiped.

Thus, $$V_{ABCD}=\frac{1}{3}V_{AD'BC'A'DB'C}=\frac{1}{3}S_{AD'BC'}\cdot\rho((A'DB'C),(AD'BC'))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot D'C'\cdot\sin{x}\cdot\rho(AB,DC)=\frac{1}{6}AB\cdot CD \cdot EF\sin{x}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had forgotten your method of constructing the associated  parallelepiped and it’s relative volume to the tetrahedron.